# Problems using bash to make an automated script in macos

Tags: bash, macos, automator

I am trying to make an automated app using Mac Automator, so that when user adds an input, that value is used to create a symbolic link from the user input to another directory. Then, it should take the value of that symbolic link to add it to Mac Finder sidebar favorites using `mysides`.

I have done the symbolic link and the adding to the sidebar favorites, but I can't seem to be able to finish the code, I hope someone is able to understand me.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for f in "$@"
do
    ln -s "$f" "/Users/Default/Documents/GoogleSync"
    basename "$f"
    s=$(basename -- "$f")
    /usr/local/bin/mysides add "$s" "file://$(echo $f | sed 's/ /%20/g')"
done
```

Comment: `file://"${f// /%20}"`

Comment: jetchisel i wanna mysides command to add the newly created folder that exist in /Users/Default/Documents/GoogleSync not the original input of a user